# Automatically Add hypen(-) in between 10 digits phone number while typing inside the text field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to automatically Add hypen(-) in between 10 digits phone number while typing inside the text field. North American standard.
I want result to be like this 647-364-3975

Am trying to do this with kepup event with typrscript. 
      The was this works is that the hypen (-) is added at when I finish typing all the phone numbers.

```
   <input id="PhoneNumberInputField" 
    (keyup)="_phoneNumberInputKeyUp($event)" [(ngModel)]="sharedVariables.PhoneNumberInput"  maxlength="10" />


   _phoneNumberInputKeyUp( event : any )
  {
      var value = this.sharedVariables.PhoneNumberInput

      if(value.length > 0){
         var formatted = value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/,"$1-$2-$3");
         this.sharedVariables.PhoneNumberInput = formatted;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme). It's a great library to take care of all kinds of masking for your project.

They have the U.S. Tel number mask as their example :D

```
mask = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
```